# pasar datos a datatable

Tags: php, datatables

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente problema tengo una tabla que lleno con una consulta  a mysql la tabla es un datatable, la ultima columna tiene un boton de eliminar el registro, he logrado que me actualize el datatable cuando borro el registro pero me lo devuelve toda la informacion en una columna
agrego el datatable

```
  <table id="reporte" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <caption style="display: none;">Consulta de Entrada de Productos</caption>

        <thead>
          <tr>                                            
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Fecha </th>
            <th>Receptor </th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Remito</th>
            <th>Eliminar</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <?php

          while($arreglo2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='min-width:40px;'>$arreglo2[0]</td>";
            echo "<td>$arreglo2[1]</td>";
            echo "<td style='min-width:60px;'>$arreglo2[2]</td>";
            echo "<td style='max-width:40px;'>$arreglo2[3]</td>";
            echo "<td style='max-width:10px;'>$arreglo2[4]</td>";
            echo "<td style='max-width:10px;'>$arreglo2[5]</td>";
            echo "<td style='max-width:10px;'>$arreglo2[6]</td>";

            echo "<td class='text-center'><span ><a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='eliminar(".$arreglo2[0].")'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a></span></td>"; 

             echo "</tr>";
          }


          ?>

         </tbody>
```

// el script de ajax para enviar los datos y eliminar

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function eliminar(id){


    var id = id;
     var conf = confirm("¿Está seguro, realmente desea eliminar el registro?");
    if (conf == true) {

      var Fechadesde= document.getElementById('Fechadesde').value;
      var Fechahasta= document.getElementById('Fechahasta').value;
      var idarea= document.getElementById('idarea').value;



    $.ajax({

      type:"POST",
      url:"deletent.php",
      data:"id="+id+"&Fechadesde="+Fechadesde+"&Fechahasta="+Fechahasta+"&idarea="+idarea,
      success: function(data){
       $('#reporte > tbody').html(data);      
      } 

    });
  }


  }



</script>
```

// el archivo deletenp.php que elimina y hace la consulta  para devolver el cuerpo de la tabla con los datos actualizados

```
    <?php



error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);

require_once("data/conexion.php");
$id = $_POST['id'];
$fechades = $_POST['Fechadesde'];
$fechahas = $_POST['Fechahasta'];
$idarea = $_POST['idarea'];






$productonuevo=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM entradas where entradas.id_entrada = '$id' ");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($productonuevo)) {

      $nuevoid = $row['id_producto'];
      $cantidad1= $row['cantidad_ent'];


    }


  /* borrar entrada */

$delete2="DELETE  FROM entradas  WHERE  entradas.id_entrada = '$id'";

$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $delete2);



$updatepro="UPDATE productos set stock_actual = stock_actual - '$cantidad1'  WHERE  productos.id_producto = '$nuevoid' ";

$result5 = mysqli_query($conn, $updatepro);

 $resultados= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT entradas.id_entrada, productos.name, entradas.cantidad_ent, entradas.date_ent, entradas.receptor, usuarios.user, entradas.remito_ent  from entradas, productos, usuarios where date(entradas.date_ent) between '$fechades' and '$fechahas' and entradas.id_area='$idarea' and productos.id_producto= entradas.id_producto and usuarios.Id_usuario= entradas.id_user");

     while($arreglo2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){
          echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> $arreglo2[0]</td>";
                echo "<td> $arreglo2[1]</td>";
                echo "<td> $arreglo2[2]</td>";
                echo "<td> $arreglo2[3]</td>";
                echo "<td> $arreglo2[4]</td>";
                echo "<td> $arreglo2[5]</td>";
                echo "<td> $arreglo2[6]</td>";

                echo "<td ><span ><a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='eliminar(".$arreglo2[0].")'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a></span></td>"; 



              }

               echo "</tr>";


 ?>
```

[image: Imagen de como quedan los datos cada campo esta una al lado del otro en un sola columna]

Comment: Perdon a todos, quiero aclarar que  el problema es que me devuelve toda la informacion en una sola columna    no en cada campo ..Saludos

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda para mí una captura donde se vea la tabla con todos los datos en una columna.

Comment: Acabo de agregar una imagen de como devuelve los datos perdon por la tardanza

Comment: ¿Que te parece si el ajax solo elimina el registro, y en vez de recargar la tabla, tan solo eliminar la fila? Mira esto: [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/teduko/edit?html,console,output)